# Using watir webdriver, unable to press & hold a point and move to connecting the other point as there is no method for the same

Tags: watir

Here is the draggable element ->

```
@browser.div(:class => "start-module-loading").div(:class => 'mod-south').div(:class => 'ui-draggable')
```

and droppable element ->

```
@browser.div(:class => "syn-module syn-module-green").div(:class => "mod-north").div(:class => 'ui-droppable')
```

Want to connect draggable element to droppable one. But not able to do so as there is no method for this action. I am using watir webdriver with cucumber

Comment: FWIW: `watir-webdriver` is deprecated; instead, use `watir` gem.  And please don't post screenshots of code.  Update your question with the (minimal amount of) HTML replicate the issue and the `watir` code you've written to address it.

Comment: Sorry about screenshot! Thanks for the update.

Comment: That screenshot was actually pretty useful in describing the problem - ie you could find out exactly what page to go to and what was supposed to happen.

Comment: Thanks again! Well, i found that i could not locate the correct element then i was able to rectify by using "present?" then "exist?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Element#drag_and_drop_on` method.

```
draggable = browser.div(id: 'node-866863') # the dot in start
drop_zone = browser.div(id: 'rec-294494')  # the triangle in send sms
draggable.drag_and_drop_on drop_zone
```

The element ids are auto-generated, so you'll need to find a way to get the related dot/triangle of your block. If you know which modules you are working with, you could use the classes (and index). For example:

```
draggable = browser.div(id: 'module-0').div(class: 'ui-draggable')
drop_zone = browser.div(id: 'module-1').div(class: 'ui-droppable')
draggable.drag_and_drop_on drop_zone
```